# What is reason for FULLTEXT index couldn't add for huge data set?

Tags: mysql, database, full-text-search, full-text-indexing

In my database contains 3 millions records. Initially haven't any FULLTEXT index in my database. Now I'm trying to add FULLTEXT index using Create index statement, that take huge time and browser showing connecting and ram goes to 70%. I feel that nothing happen to database. what should I follow? Is there any other way to add FULLTEXT index? If I'm add FULLTEXT index is that affect to next inserting values? 1st I want to anyhow add FULLTEXT index to my table. I'm using Xammp MySql database.

Answer (score 2):

1.Create the dummy table like your original table structure.
2.create indexes on your dummy table which want you.
3.take a dump from your original table and import to dummy.
4.drop the original table and rename the dummy table to original name.

Comment: I tried previous way. Suddenly my sql server restarted. Now I'm not sure weather FULLTEXT index happened or not. How I check it? (Weather fulltext index added or not)

Comment: @Maduri,`show index  from table_name;`,please care for your databackup

Comment: :) .Thanx lot dear. That showing FULLTEXT index is in my column.(What's meaning of "Cardinality 1". 1 mean is that only affected to one record? )I think that affected :). One thing to have ask. When I'm inserting records again and again should I run the FULLTEXT index adding code or is that affect every record after one time create?

Comment: Table  Non_unique Key_name Seq_in_index Column_name Collation  Cardinality  Sub_part  Packed  Null  Index_type  Comment                                                           
corpus  1  Cor_Sentence(column name)  1  Cor_Sentence(column name)  NULL  1  NULL  NULL     FULLTEXT

Comment: @Maduri,http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2566211/what-is-cardinality-in-mysql please refer this

Comment: Thanx dear. I got the point. One thing, do I need to again run FULLTEXT adding code when I inserting record again and again?

Comment: Thanx lot dear. Have a nice day :).