# Figuring out cardinality

Tags: mysql

How is cardinality calculated?

When I do:

```
select count(distinct(content_type)) from mturk_imdbentry
```

I get 10 distinct values. But when I check the database, it lists the cardinality of that column as 19. Why is this so?

Comment: DISTINCT will select only one unique value for each row in your content_type column, which means you must have 9 duplicate values in that column.

Comment: @Alex I actually have millions of duplicates of these values.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is cardinality in MySQL?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2566211/what-is-cardinality-in-mysql)

Comment: Is the result the same after You run `ANALYZE TABLE`? Maybe 19 is an outdated estimation.

Comment: MySQL docs say: `Cardinality: An __estimate__ of the number of unique values in the index` ... `This is updated by running ANALYZE TABLE`

Comment: Just an aside,where do you check the cardinality in mysql?Without running a query

Comment: @Mihai: `SHOW INDEX` displays cardinality

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method used for the estimation for "cardinality" value depends on the storage engine.

InnoDB uses sampling. How that's done (number of index dives, number of pages inspected), and when that happens, depends on the version of InnoDB, and the settings of some variables, e.g.

```
use_legacy_innodb_algorithm
innodb_stats_on_metadata
innodb_stats_persistent
innodb_stats_persistent_sample_pages
innodb_stats_auto_recalc
innodb_stats_method
```

With MyISAM:

```
myisam_stats_method
```

Some additional information is available in the MySQL Reference Manual

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/myisam-index-statistics.html