# Which on-disk database has the fastest read

Tags: mysql, database, postgresql

Hi I have a table in mysql (storage engine is InnoDB) with the following format

id integer,
word1 varchar(50),
word2 varchar(50),
field1 int,
field2 float,

The number of records is in the ballpark of 100 millions.  I need to query for around 1000 records at a time for a word that matches 'word1'.  I have an index on word1 and another on word2.  When I run a query like

```
   select * from mytable where word1='someword'
```

it takes 20-40 secs to retrieve the data.  Is there anything I can do to optimize the read?  Will using any other db bring significant savings in time?

Update for Devon:

I am running this on my personal lenovo laptop. Its a 1TB HDD(SATA/5200 rpm/EXT4), intel i7, 8GB RAM.

This is the result after running

```
 show indexes from mytable\G
```

`mysql> show indexes from mytable\G
*************************** 1. row ***************************
        Table: mytable
   Non_unique: 0
     Key_name: PRIMARY
 Seq_in_index: 1
  Column_name: id
    Collation: A
  Cardinality: 86308613
     Sub_part: NULL
       Packed: NULL
         Null: 
   Index_type: BTREE
      Comment: 
Index_comment: 
*************************** 2. row ***************************
        Table: mytable
   Non_unique: 1
     Key_name: mytable_word1
 Seq_in_index: 1
  Column_name: word1
    Collation: A
  Cardinality: 198
     Sub_part: NULL
       Packed: NULL
         Null: 
   Index_type: BTREE
      Comment: 
Index_comment: 
*************************** 3. row ***************************
        Table: mytable
   Non_unique: 1
     Key_name: mytable_word2
 Seq_in_index: 1
  Column_name: word2
    Collation: A
  Cardinality: 198
     Sub_part: NULL
       Packed: NULL
         Null: 
   Index_type: BTREE
      Comment: 
Index_comment:`

Comment: Which DBMS are you using?  Which storage engine?

Comment: Hi Devon, as mentioned the dbms is mysql.  I have added storage engine (Innodb).   Thank you for the feedback.

Comment: 40 seconds is pretty high.  What type of disk setup do you have?  Show the full query you are running and `SHOW INDEXES FROM mytable`.

Comment: What's the table's size? 100 mln of rows could mean quite a few gigs if average row size is large. Big tables are for good hardware/DBMS/partition scheme only.

Comment: i user4419802, the table size is 7.22Gb

Comment: The big issue here is the 5200rpm drive.  That is just not made for large database activity because of the slow seek time.  Daniel covered some good topics.  Depending on how much RAM you have, you can resolve this by increasing your innodb buffer pool, but for a table like this, you'd need few gigs of RAM available to it and it will only help for subsequent selects.  Other than that, a small SSD would probably reduce 40s to <4s.

Comment: How many results come back from the SELECT?  If those rows were scattered around the table, then divide by 100 to get a crude estimate of the number of seconds to fetch them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The cardinality of `mytable_word1` indicates there are only about 198 distinct values for `word1`. Compare this to the cardinality of the unique index, which is about 86.3 million values.
(see [What is cardinality in MySQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2566211) for explanations if needed).

So the number rows that match any specific word is expected to be (statistically speaking) `86.3*10^6 / 200` = `431500` results, scattered  throughout the big table.

Reading scattered blocks on an HDD is a worst case, plus on your laptop, you have a single and slow HDD. `20-40s` needed for that SELECT is not surprising.
That problem is not specific to any particular database.

To speed this up, you may consider partitioning the big table, for example along the first letter of `word1`, but that won't help if you also need to search on `word2` independently of `word1`.

Comment: PARTITIONing on the first letter is unlikely to help much.  The 431K rows will then be scattered around one partition.  With luck some of them will fall into the same block -- this is what you are hoping for, but the statistics say it is not likely enough.